Getting error Already registered a copy: org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSubQuery
if (filterParamModel == null || pageSize == 1) {
    pageModel.setTotalRecords(-1);
} else {
    CriteriaQuery<Long> countQuery = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
    Root<AlertTbl> countRoot = countQuery.from(AlertTbl.class);
    countQuery.select(cb.count(countRoot));
    countQuery.where(cb.and(predicateArr));
    Long count = entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
    pageModel.setTotalRecords(count.intValue());
}

return pageModel;

Someone told me to use StringBuilder but there are a lot of methods like this so I can't do that. I just migrated to Spring Boot 3 and getting this error.

Please add the full stacktrace.
